# Is it possible to build Typescript React Components Individually for use in legacy html apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, rollupjs

I'm researching ways to move away from legacy front ends using micro front ends.

Say I have a React Component Library using Typescript, is it possible to build the components individually so that I can then import them into the legacy html/js app with `script` tags and use them?

I know that Angular has Angular Elements which allow you to export the components as Web Components so I'm looking for something similar in React.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched about this subject in a while, and my conclusion is to use web components with react https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html, however, I've not perform any proof of concept yet. Finally I used vuejs that it integrate with legacy websites very easy.

Comment: I've had a look at that. That link talks about using web components *in* React or React *in* web components - not using a React Component as a Web Component. NB: I'm not looking specifically to use web components, just a way to build typescript react components individually for use in plain html/js.

Comment: Yes, I understand you, react component self can't render in plain html, for that it use the web component as intermediary, I think you should try a proof concept with this react component to web component converter https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web-component